# If I'm using Netlify DNS servers, is there a way I can get emails to forward to a Gmail address? (for a host on Google domains)

Tags: domain-name-system, email, email-server, mx-record

I'm trying to use Netlify (https://www.netlify.com/) for deployment to a custom domain which has worked. But in order to do that, I've switched from Google's DNS servers (the domain is registered on Google Domains) to using Netlify's DNS.

In theory it seems like I can change the MX records at `https://app.netlify.com/account/dns/<domain>` — but what can I change them to if I don't have a host? I know I can buy Google Apps for my domain, but I don't actually want anything from it except forwarding so it seems like overkill.

All I want is forwarding of specific emails to a gmail address for now (though I'd be open to just forwarding all emails to the domain if need be).

Comment: You can’t exchange email without a service running to do that. So if you don’t have the service hosted somewhere, you don’t have anything to point the DNS records to. Many domain registrars offer free email forwarding or hosting. So if Google doesn’t do that, perhaps you should consider moving the domain.

Comment: Google domains email forwarding only works when you are using google DNS servers. https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3251241?hl=en

Comment: It sounds like the only way to do this is either to switch to a registrar that provides email forwarding without requiring using their DNS servers (which do that?), or use some 3rd party to forward emails.